# Multiple AttributeTargets in AttributeUsage

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
...
}
```

I want this custom attribute used both on **properties** and **fileds** but not others. How do I assign multiple targets(`AttributeTargets.Property` and `AttributeTargets.Field`)? Or It's just not possible?

And `AttributeTargets.All` is not what I want.

Answer (score 37):

You can specify multiple targets like this, by using the `|` (bitwise OR) operator to specify multiple enum values:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    ...
}
```

The bitwise OR operator works with the AttributeTargets enum because its values are assigned a particular way and it's marked with the Flags attribute.

If you care to, you can read more here:

- [C# Fundamentals: Combining Enum Values with Bit-Flags](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/07/22/c-fundamentals-combining-enum-values-with-bit-flags.aspx)
- [Understand how bitwise operators work (C# and VB.NET examples)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/544990/Understand-how-bitwise-operators-work-Csharp-and-V)